# What is the significance of the asimov system?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

[image]

The caption for the acronym is "Accuracy System Image Module for Optimum Velocity" which spells out asimov, but I was wondering if the anime producers have revealed if the logo at the bottom was just a homage or if there is any actual significance to the logo itself?

Comment: Please specify: what kind of significance do you have in mind?

Comment: @Red The kind the people who put in the reference had in mind. As stated in the question: "I was wondering if the anime producers have revealed if the logo at the bottom was just a homage or if there is any actual significance to the logo itself"

Comment: @ton.yeung It's not clear to me what you mean by "significance". It is obviously an homage to Isaac Asimov, and, as Septian's answer points out, it is also the name of the system that drives the Terran kataphrakts. What else are you looking for? (e.g. an in-universe reason why it's named after Isaac Asimov?)

Comment: @senshin you guys are focusing on my usage of the word significance, when what my question focuses on is whether or not there has been comments on using asimov's name from **the people who made the anime**. I fully understand that asimov refers to the science fiction writer, its in my post. Right before the part about "any actual significance".

Answer (score 3):

ASIMOV is kind of OS (or program), used by Earth force.

[image]

It's main module to control kataphrakt as you seen in the image above. But who develop it, what else it can do, it's still unknown (for now).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. As you wrote in your answer "But who develop it, what else it can do, it's still unknown (for now)." The anime has not made any reference to it other than what you showed here, I'm wondering if there is any other sources which *does* explain the reference to asimov.

Answer (score 2):

The name itself just seems to be a reference to the science fiction writer Issac Asimov who the show draws a lot of parallels to. The team behind the show seem to be classic sci-fi fans.

Edit: In Asimov's Short Novel series including The Caves of Steel, The Naked Sun a detective is charged with investigating a murder of a member of a group of people that left earth to colonize space. These select few created an elitist society with a small but pure, healthy population. Much like American plantation aristocracy. These colonists or "spacers" saw their distant relatives as inferior  and alien due to the lack of attention the Earthlings give to genetic filtering or a seemingly strange social system. Auro Kumar Datta can explain it better that me here: http://worldanimeclub.com/2014/10/12/aldnoah-zero-isaac-asimov-revisited/

Comment: do you have any reference to back up your answer?

Comment: `draws a lot of parallels to` Please include the details which you think is similar to something Isaac Asimov has written.